# Ionic 3 Cannot find module '@angular/core'. and Cannot find module 'rxjs'

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

i am trying to run my project that i am using firestore in it, however i came across this error and i haven't been able to figure out a solution for it. Because, whenever i do ionic serve on my CMD, i can't get my page to run, due to me getting a list of errors, as it follows on this picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtFX8.jpg. It gives me errors saying i have problems with my angularfire2.d.ts, that being the first set of errors.

As for the second set of errors it says i have problems in my firebase.module.d.ts.

At last this is the list of the errors i get on my google chrome

```
Typescript Error
Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
node_modules/@angular/fire/angularfire2.d.ts
import { InjectionToken, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
```

Finally:

```
Typescript Error
Cannot find module 'rxjs'.
/node_modules/@angular/fire/angularfire2.d.ts
```

Added Package.json

```
    {
  "name": "FirestoreCrud",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ionic-app-scripts serve",
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.11",
    "@ionic-native/core": "~4.12.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "~4.12.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "~4.12.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
    "firebase": "^5.4.2",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.11",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.3.2",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.2.0",
    "typescript": "~2.6.2"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}
```

Comment: Can you please share your package.json file? I think there might be a dependency issue.

Comment: It looks like you have the correct packages in `package.json`.  To know why TypeScript isn't finding them, we'll need to see your `tsconfig.json`.  It may help if you run `tsc` with the `--traceResolution` flag.  Or you can just publish a repository and I'll troubleshoot for you.

Answer (score -1):

check your node_modules if the following modules exist,if not install them through npm